What are the FFmpeg encoding settings necessary for web playback?
I'm attempting to convert videos recorded on an iPhone (specifically the 15 Pro Max which I believe was running 17.6.1 based on metadata) to play in browsers, especially safari on said iPhone, but can't seem to find the proper combination of settings to get it to work. Client previously was using iPhone 13 and it worked well enough just using libx264, but that no longer works with the newer version.
Here's the FFmpeg command:
ffmpeg -y -i {source_path} -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1 -b:a 256k -ac 2 {output_path}

I've tried piecing together lots of different options, but to no avail. I tried setting the profile to baseline and level 4.0 (and 3.1) which failed encoding because the source was 10 bit, so I added pix_fmt yuv420p and that got it to encode but ios safari threw media not supported. Tried different levels (4.0 and 3.1), different profiles (baseline, main, high, and high10) and a handful of other random copy/pastes I've found around the internet and nothing has worked so far.
Here's the FFprobe output for the source video:
ffprobe version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1+esm6 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1+esm6 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '_20240924010655_66f2f1af2362a_file_path':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2024-09-19T23:01:19.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: [redacted]
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: [redacted]
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 15 Pro Max
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 17.6.1
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2024-09-19T18:01:19-0500
  Duration: 00:00:30.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9467 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/arib-std-b67), 1920x1080, 9251 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2024-09-19T23:01:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 167 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-09-19T23:01:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-09-19T23:01:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-09-19T23:01:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
    Stream #0:4(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-09-19T23:01:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 4


The FFprobe output shows the following:
encoder         : HEVC

HEVC is the more advanced codec that iOS uses nowadays instead of libx264. With in mind, changing that to libx265 should work.

sorry, in all of my focus I forgot firefox was a thing and from what I can see it doesn't properly support 265, but it did make me look further into my assumption that it has to be 264 and I might be able to get away with webm
